# Explain why it is true that if $7^{30}$, $7^{20}$ and $7^{12}$ are not congruent to 1 mod 61, then 7 is a primitive root mod 61

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Notice that $60 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$. Explain why it is true that if $7^{30}$, $7^{20}$ and $7^{12}$ are not congruent to $1 \mod 61$, then $7$ is a primitive root $\mod 61$.

Here is what I have so far:

Start by supposing that $7$ has order $e \mod 61$. What do you know about the order $e$?

Comment: If you consider the order as a natural number, you have that $e|60$.

Comment: Surely you have had an exercise or example like the following: Given this element $g$ of a group of order ten we can deduce that the order of $g$ has to be one of $1,2,5,10$. If it were $2$, then $g^2=1$. If it were $5$, then $g^5=1$. If it were $1$, then both of these would hold. Ergo, if neither holds, then $g$ is of order ten. Extend that (and read André's answer if you get stuck).

Answer (score 4):

The order of $7$ divides $60$. Any proper divisor of $60$ divides at least one of $30$, $20$, or $12$. So if $7$ had order $\lt 60$, one of the powers mentioned in the question would be congruent to $1$ modulo $61$.

**Remark:** The assertion that any proper divisor of $60$ divides at least one of $30$, $20$, and $12$ can be checked by mentally going through the proper divisors of $60$: there are not many. Or else we can note that $60=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5$. Any proper divisor of $60$ must be missing at least one copy of a prime divisor of $60$. So any proper divisor of $60$ divides at least one of $2\cdot 3\cdot 5$, $2^2\cdot 5$, or $2^2\cdot 3$.  T

Comment: Excellent as usual, André Nicolas. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: note that $61$ is prime and use Fermat's little theorem. If $7^{30}, 7^{20}$ and $7^{12}$ are not congruent to $1$ mod $61$, what can we say about the order of $7$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/61\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$?